# Recommendations for 'shopping'

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, shopping

Not to pick on anyone, but there've been a few recent questions that come very close to bordering on failing our [faq]

Examples:

[Recommendation for accommodation in Montreal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8217/101)

[Can anyone recommend a good restaurant in central southside Dublin?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8211/101)

[Can anyone recommend a good hiking trail in Scotland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6846/101)

[Can anyone recommend the most interesting 2 or 3 day cycle in Vietnam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3622/101)

I'd like to  discuss these as examples.  Some are 'fineish', but we're only going to get more, and the problem I have is that there's no definitive answer that can satisfactorily answer a question.  Most interesting 2-3 day cycle - to whom?  Good hiking trail in Scotland? Needs more details?  Accommodation in Montreal - there are hundreds of hotels/hostels/campsites/couchsurfing etc.

I'd prefer they were rephrased as "I want accommodation in x that meets these 5 criteria".  Essentially, answers should not be subjective and start discussions.

I'd like to flesh out the [FAQ] to be more precise on this, and start being stricter about questions coming in like this, but would like feedback on how it should read.  Thoughts? Suggestions? This is one time a discussion is good :)

Answer (score 3):

Well we already have the "specific criteria" criteria for suggestion / recommendation questions. Why not just enforce that everywhere?

- It might help if we can get some help from the system though.

  When you start asking a question with "best" the system will insert a loud little warning about the question box that such questions are likely to be closed.

  Maybe we can work with the SE people to try to detect suggestion / recommendation questions in the same way and put in a loud little warning that such questions must have specific criteria or will be closed.
- Also we could change the tag name from [recommendations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) to [specific-recommendations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-recommendations) or something like that as a way to nag people that such questions must always be specific.

(Oh by the way I don't consider these shopping questions, those are a different problem which require different approaches.)

Comment: yeah, thus the 'shopping' in quotes, I couldn't think of a better way of describing it.

Comment: The question title made me expect it would about questions like this recent one: **[Where to buy beeswax in Wroclaw, Poland or an online source that ships to Poland](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8240/where-to-buy-beeswax-in-wroclaw-poland-or-an-online-source-that-ships-to-poland)**